# Oracle error in MyBatis XML Mapper file, but not in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I have a query in a MyBatis XML wrapper that results in a `ORA-00904 invalid identifier`. However, when I copy the statement shown in the log it runs.

The log message is

```
SQL: select /*+ parallel(AUTO) */ avg(DURATION) AVERAGE_SESSION_DURATION              
from sc_report_new.sc_hub_session_activity schsa             
    inner join sc_hub_users schu on schsa.user_key=schu.user_key             
    inner join sc_hub_user_types schut on chut.user_type_id=schu.user_type_id             
    inner join sc_hub_content_master schcm on chcm.trace_id_key=schsa.hub_key                                                     
WHERE schsa.FISCAL_QUARTER_ID = '2020Q2'
```

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SCHSA"."FISCAL_QUARTER_ID": invalid identifier

```
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76)
```

The snippet of the mapper query is

```
    <select id="getDashboardAverageSessionDuration" 
            resultType="int" 
            parameterType="com.mycompany.salesconnect.screport.model.AuthorizedHubRequest">
            select /*+ parallel(AUTO) */ 
                   avg(DURATION) AVERAGE_SESSION_DURATION 
            from sc_report_new.sc_hub_session_activity schsa
            inner join sc_hub_users schu
            on schsa.user_key=schu.user_key
            inner join sc_hub_user_types schut
            on schut.user_type_id=schu.user_type_id
            inner join sc_hub_content_master schcm
            on schcm.trace_id_key=schsa.hub_key
            <include refid="com.mycompany.salesconnect.screport.mapper.hubportfolio.Common.joinHubAuthorizations">
                <property name="hubAuthorizations" value="hubAuthorizations"/>
            </include>
            <where>
                 <if test="hubRequestFilter.dateRangeSpecified">
                     schsa.time_stamp
                     BETWEEN to_date(#{hubRequestFilter.fromDate}, 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                     AND
                            to_date(#{hubRequestFilter.toDate}, 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                 </if>
                 <if test="!hubRequestFilter.dateRangeSpecified">
                    <if test="hubRequestFilter.quarterListByNameNotEmpty">
                        SCHSA.FISCAL_QUARTER_ID IN 

                        <foreach item="quarterName" collection="hubRequestFilter.quarterListByName" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                            <bind name="quarterId" 
                                  value="@com.mycompany.salesconnect.screport.dao.SCHubPortfolioUtil@getQuarterAsId(quarterName)"/>
                             #{quarterName}
                        </foreach>
                    </if>
                    <if test="hubRequestFilter.quarterListByIdNotEmpty">
                       SCHSA.FISCAL_QUARTER_ID IN 
                       <foreach item="quarterId" collection="hubRequestFilter.quarterListById" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                             #{quarterId}
                        </foreach>
                    </if>
                    
                 </if>
                <include refid="com.mycompany.salesconnect.screport.mapper.hubportfolio.Common.whereHubRequestFilter"><property name="hubRequestFilter" value="hubRequestFilter"></property></include>
                <include refid="com.mycompany.salesconnect.screport.mapper.hubportfolio.Common.whereHubAuthorizations"><property name="hubAuthorizations" value="hubAuthorizations"></property></include>
            </where>
    </select>
```

I looked for non-printable characters in the XML and didn't see any.  Stating what should be obvious, the SC_HUB_SESSION_ACTIVITY table has a FISCAL_QUARTER_ID field.  Interestingly, if I choose another SCHSA column, it works.  For some reason the system singles out this field for arbitrarily not working.

Comment: Is the query in the XML wrapper different?

Comment: @alexherm I edited the question with the snippet of the mapper that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue with MyBatis but rather not pointing to the same database as the SQL Developer that I was using.